# Can anyone can help me with this circle exercise?

Tags: conic-sections

Determine the center and the radius of the circle equation:

$$2x^2 + 2y^2 - 8x - 12y +8=0$$

Please if you know it tell what should I do with the coefficients of the squares.

Comment: You might find it easier if you divided both sides by $2$

Comment: Did it for him.(so he approaches as familiar circle, not a special case of conics)

Comment: @Ceco Welcome to Math SE! Consider showing your efforts in the question.

Comment: @Narasimham Please do not modify the substance of a question, even if you think you are doing it "for" the OP.

Comment: OK,taken, but please see his posts on same day, same way.

Comment: @Narasimham Is this related? How? If you think some post lacks personal input then comment and/or downvote and/or vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to rewrite this like below:
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=R^2$$

for your case first divide whole equation by 2 then your equation will be $x^2+y^2-4x-6y+4=0$ now we have: $(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2=3^2$ so, the center of your circle is $(2,3)$ and its radius is 3.